# Eclipse: No Java-Application

Tags: java, eclipse

I read that problem already sometimes here but no of these could help me so i decided just to ask now.
I'm learning java ath the moment and i had this:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Divisionberechnung 
{
public static void main (String[] args)
{
    Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in);

    int dividend, divisor ;
    int quotient, rest ;

    System.out.println("Dividend eingeben:");
    dividend = scan.nextInt();

    System.out.println("Divisor eingeben:");
    divisor = scan.nextInt();

    quotient = dividend / divisor;
    rest = dividend % divisor;

    System.out.println( dividend + " / " + divisor + " ist " + quotient );
    System.out.println( dividend + " % " + divisor + " ist " + rest );
    System.out.println( quotient + " * " + divisor + " + " + rest + " ist " +      (quotient*divisor+rest));    
}

}
```

When i started Eclipse and just began to write this and ended it runned normal and worked. But when i closed Eclipse and opened that file again i couldn't choose run as Java Apllication anymore. When i click on Run there just appears a window where i can choose between two "Ant Builds". But No Java Apllication? Where is the problem?

Comment: try to right-click on your text box, where your source code is, and run from there (Run As... option)

Comment: Go to Run -> run Configurations -> Double Click Java Application -> New Configuration ->

Comment: I can choose there "Run Configurations...". But i don't knwo what to do there ._.

Comment: Look for Java Application . if there is no configuration within Java Application. Doiuble click "Java Application" to create one.

Comment: You will see the project name and main class there. If its all good till that. Just execute Run. Fron next time whenever you will do run, it will pick this last executed  configuration.

Comment: OK i made a new Java-Application at "Run Configuration..." and tipped in the main methode but the problem is with the project name now. I can't choose any project there.

Comment: Go to your project -> Right click -> Run As -> Run Configuration and then create a new configuration.

Comment: http://www.bildercache.de/bild/20140225-212246-175.png

Comment: Surpisingly nothing showing up in your project and packages. Please create a project first and then add the java class within the project.

Comment: But i already created thsui project when i started it. I made this java project and everything worked. Only after i closed and restarded eclipse this happened. The porject was saved. I really donÄt understand what is happening here.

Comment: File -> Import -> General -> Import and Import your project again if its there in your workspace.

Answer (score 0):

You can try and add a new run configuration: Run -> Run Configurations ... -> Select "Java Appliction" and click "New".

Alternatively use the shortcut: place the cursor in the class, then press Alt + Shift + X to open up a context menu, then press J.

Comment: Of course ^^ But same problem always :( As said when i started the project and finished I just clicked on Run and everything worked. Now this windows with "Ant Buidls" appears and I can't choose Java-Application.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Run -> run Configurations -> Double Click Java Application -> New Configuration

Make sure that your project name and main class name appears correctly and click run.

From Next time when you will do Run , it will pick this last used configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you change your view and Prespective , In your case you Will want to choose "JAVA" And "!
Console"

[image]

Comment: Hey @Ankluas  go to open prespective and click on other , you will see one that says JAVA choose it